# Simple recursive method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write very simple recursive method, but can't make it work.
I have simple comments hierarchy with ids like here:

```
1--
   2--
      4--
   3--
      5--
```

Now I want to save their ids in array (tree order) `[0]=1, [1]=2, [2]=4, [3]=3, [4]=5`

I start building this array in Entry model with

```
def comment_tree
  comment = self.comments.find(1) #it's temporary, just to check if it works
  return recur(comment,0)
end

private
def recur(comment,i)
  @tree[i]=comment.id #added attr_accessible :@tree
  if comment.children.any?
    comment.children.each {|c| recur(c,i+1)}
  else
    return
  end
  @tree
end
```

This doesn't work, as block runs twice the same counter argument `recur(4,2)` and `recur(3,2)`. I need something like global $i to keep this arras index, but I'm sure there must be better way of doing it. The same is with @tree, do I really have to add new variable to model just to use it as a return parameter from recur method? I won't use it in any other place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
def comment_tree
  comment = self.comments.find(1)
  tree = []
  recur(comment, tree)
  tree
end

private
def recur(comment, acc)
  acc << comment.id
  comment.children.each {|c| recur(c, acc) }
end
```